Allow Restricted permission in android
I am creating a parental control app in react native but when i am installing the app the app setting is restricted and need to allow the special app permission
I want these two permission allowed when i install my app on phone so if any one have the solution please tell me

"I want these two permission allowed when i install my app on phone..." The app user needs to grant most of the permissions at runtime. Not all permissions are even available for regular applications, but only e.g. for device manufacturers. What permissions are you trying to get?

i am trying to get the permission of special app acess

Ah, these things: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting-special. In any case a user needs to grant the permission as the documentation explains. I have no idea how that works in React.

Seeing and seeing the programming language you are using, I highly discourage you from doing this. android device owner. Implementing these features can be tricky, and the fact that you start asking questions before you've even gotten your hands dirty means you'll have a hard time moving on to the next step.

do you have any solution because i know the app is restricted due to google play policy but about special app access for the listening notification if you have any solution then please tell me and thank you

I would highly suggest looking at the documentation of permissions.

Android
iOS


I have already looked in to it but there is not solution for that
